# Adding subView in main view controller not able to perform button click event

Tags: swift

```
let secondVC = SecondViewController(nibName: "SecondViewController", bundle: nil)        
        var cgRectFrame = secondVC.view.frame
        cgRectFrame.origin = CGPoint(x: self.view.frame.origin.x, y:self.view.frame.origin.y+64)
        cgRectFrame.size = CGSize(width: self.view.frame.size.width, height: self.view.frame.size.height)
        secondVC.view.frame = cgRectFrame
        IBMainView.addSubview(secondVC.view)
```

Answer (score 0):

try `secondVC.view.isUserInteractionEnabled = true`

Answer (score 0):

just add  "self.addChildViewController(viewController_object)" in code

```
    let secondVC = SecondViewController(nibName: "SecondViewController", bundle: nil)

    self.addChildViewController(secondVC)
    var cgRectFrame = secondVC.view.frame
    cgRectFrame.origin = CGPoint(x: self.view.frame.origin.x, y:self.view.frame.origin.y+64)
    cgRectFrame.size = CGSize(width: self.view.frame.size.width, height: self.view.frame.size.height)
    secondVC.view.frame = cgRectFrame
    IBMainView.addSubview(secondVC.view)
```